# Angular 2: Pass templateUrl as an attribute

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Is there a way to pass the templateUrl as an attribute to an Angular-2 component.

We need this as the templates are getting dynamically rendered in a backend system and we want to specify the template right in the generated HTML (where the component is instantiated).

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

it might not be a perfect answer for your question, but there is such a thing as server side rendering.

https://angularu.com/VideoSession/2015sf/angular-2-server-rendering

Comment: Hi,
Yes I know about this, but the backend server is already defined (based on a enterprise service), this means we just need to have the possibility to define the target URL where the template should be loaded from in the rendered HTML.

Any idea?

Comment: i dont think that dynamic urls are allowed due to security reasons.
maybe you can use this:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html